# How do I check through <input>(x5) and only submit when they don't have a class, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of code I've been working on but there's a problem, here's the code:

```
$('form input').keyup(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('field-error')){

        $('.btn').addClass('no-submit').removeClass('btn');
        $('.error-notify').show();          
    }
    else{

        $('.no-submit').addClass('btn').removeClass('no-submit');
        $('.error-notify').hide();

        $('.btn').click(function(){ 
            $(this).parent().find('form').submit();
        });
    }
});
```

What I'd like to happen is..when all form inputs(x5) have been checked and there are no instances of any `form input`s having the '.field-error' class the then `.btn` class becomes clickable and the form can be submitted

If you'd like me to further make clear what I mean, just let me know.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: @James here it is on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PqsAD/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
if($(this).hasClass('field-error'))
```

To this:

```
if($(this).siblings().andSelf().hasClass('field-error'))
```

I think this is what you want  (see [this Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jameswiseman/PqsAD/2/)), though am not totally sure. From what I can see it doesn't disable when the field = '?'.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as checking the length of inputs that have the field-error class?

```
var failures = $('input.field-error');
if (failures.length) {
    //still have errors
} else {
    // good to go
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things.  The approach would be to create a submit handler for your form and catch it there:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event){
    if ($(this).find('input.field-error').length > 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});
```

Second thing.  Sounds like you just need jQuery.validate, you can create any kind of custom validation you need.